# tokyo-tyrant in memory database like redis or can it grow larger then memory and retrieve from harddrive

Tags: memory-management, tokyo-tyrant

Tokyo-tyrant in memory database like redis(allthough redis has VM?) or can it grow larger then memory and retrieve from harddrive. If so how does it achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokyo Tyrant is just a network interface to Tokyo Cabinet, not an actual database server.
Tokyo Cabinet has support for both in-memory and on-file storages.
When you start Tokyo Tyrant's **ttserver** the database name you specify is the type of storage that will be used. For instance, if you start up ttserver with:

```
ttserver "*" -- in-memory hash
ttserver "+" -- in-memory tree
ttserver /var/ttserver/casket.tch -- on-disk hash
ttserver /var/ttserver/casket.tcb -- on-disk b-tree
ttserver /var/ttserver/casket.tct -- on-disk fixed-length
```